# Kotlin specific way using coroutines to create typical consumer thread for queue

Tags: java, multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Suppose I have a background running thread that will consume events from a queue

```
public class Consumer implements Runnable {
    BlockingQueue<Object> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            queue.take();
        }
    }
}
```

I know it is possible to implement it just like that, but is there a fancy way to do this same thing using kotlin coroutines? I've been searching for it, but haven't been able to find anything.

In kotlin I would also like to use the `Channel<E>` from the coroutines library instead of `BlockingQueues`, if possible.

Comment: Use `actor { ... }`, which will provide you with both the queue and the handler code.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works fine.